# How to determine how many bytes / hr are being written to my SD card

Tags: linux, debian, embedded, flash-memory

I have a Debian embedded Linux system that uses an SD card as the RFS.  What is a reliable way to determine how many bytes / hr are being written to the SD card?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of ways:

- If you can get SMART data from an SD cart with smartctl, it may have a bytes written counter (no idea if this is possible). This will be the most accurate, as it will count all partitions and also not be lost over reboot. It may also be able to count any write-amplification caused by erase block size and/or wear-leveling.
- Depending on the filesystem you're using, there may be a write counter. For example, ext4 tracks lifetime writes, which you can see with `dumpe2fs -h`.
- The kernel keeps I/O counters. There are several programs to see them (they're in /sys and /proc, so you don't actually need special programs). For example `iostat /dev/sda` will show you how many kB have been written since boot, and the kB/sec also since boot. `iostat` can also show you current values (e.g., `iostat /dev/sda 10` will show you values for every 10 seconds).

The basic approach to turn a counter into a per-time measure is to take one reading and record it, then take another some time later, subtract, and divide.

Example:

1. At 0600 hours, 10 KB have been written.
2. At 1000 hours, 50 KB have been written.
3. 50kB - 10kB = 40kB; 40kB ÷ 4 hours = 10 kB/hour.